# C++ error, Calling a class member from a function

Tags: c++, class, sdl

I am working on building a game, and I get a compiling error `apply_surface was not declared in this scope.` the **error is in line 95**, in the function `User::show()`.

EDIT: Now that it is fized, the image "baz", is not showing up on the screen. sorry for the edit.

```
/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2013)
 and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//The headers
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <string>

SDL_Surface *background = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *baz = NULL;
SDL_Event event;

void cleanup()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(background);
    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
    SDL_FreeSurface(baz);
    SDL_Quit;
}

bool quit = false;

class User
{
private:
    SDL_Surface *baz = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
    int x;
    int y;
    int xVel;
    int yVel;
public:
    void keys();
    void move();
    void show();
    void user();
};
void User::keys()
{
    while(quit == false)
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
                quit = true;
        }
    
    Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
    
    
    if(keystates[SDLK_d] )
    {
        User::xVel+=50;
    }
    if(keystates[SDLK_a])
    {
        User::xVel-=50;
    }
    if(keystates[SDLK_s])
    {
        User::yVel+=50;
    }
    if(keystates[SDLK_w])
    {
        User::yVel-=50;
    }
    if(keystates[SDLK_ESCAPE])
    {
        cleanup();
    }
}

void User::user()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    xVel = 0;
    yVel = 0;
}

void User::move()
{
    x+=xVel;
    y+=yVel;
    x-=xVel;
}


void User::show()
{
    apply_surface(x,y,baz,screen);
    SDL_Flip( screen );
}

void apply_surface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination )
{ //Temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
    
    SDL_Rect offset;
    //Get the offsets
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y; //Blit the surface
    SDL_BlitSurface( source, NULL, destination, &offset );
}



int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,400,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);
    background = IMG_Load("background.png");
    baz = IMG_Load("baz.png");
    apply_surface(0,0,background,screen);
    
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    
    while( quit == false )
    {
        User Baz;
        Baz.user();
        Baz.keys();
        Baz.move();
        Baz.show();
        if(quit == true)
        {
            cleanup();
        }        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Move the definition of `apply_surface()` above the function that uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `apply_surface()` function is not declared within the scope

So move your code :

```
void apply_surface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination )
{ //Temporary rectangle to hold the offsets

    SDL_Rect offset;
    //Get the offsets
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y; //Blit the surface
    SDL_BlitSurface( source, NULL, destination, &offset );
}
```

to the top ( before you use it )

Or else

Add a function prototype at the top like this :

```
void apply_surface( int, int, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*);
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you included the arguments to the functions.

Comment: did it as u said @kfsone

Comment: The other option is that he just adds a prototype for it before the first time he uses it: `apply_surface(x,y,baz,screen);`

Comment: Sorry, laughing too hard that he posted it as is...
`void apply_surface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination );`

Comment: yes of course @kfsone, but the way i told doesn't even need that extra piece of code also...anyways i'll include the way you said also.. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Including the arguments (doesn't need the whole routine body) can help if the OP actually has it in a header but with the wrong arguments, when all you're saying is "move the function up a few lines"