# void * function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have made a typedef for a function pointer that takes in an integer and returns a void *:

```
typedef void* (*fp)(int index);
```

I then made a struct that contains a fp and another struct of the same type:

```
typedef struct fp_holder {
    fp function_pointer;
    iterable *next;
} fp_holder;
```

I am trying to figure out how to call fp inside a fp_holder.

To test this out, I did the following:

```
void *test_fp(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        printf('H');
        fflush(stdout);
        return [something_that_works];
    }
    else if (index == 1) {
        printf('e');
        fflush(stdout);
        return [something_that_works];
    }
    else if (index == 2) {
        printf('l');
        fflush(stdout);
        return [something_that_works];
    }
    else if (index == 3) {
        printf('l');
        fflush(stdout);
        return [something_that_works];
    }
    else if (index == 4) {
        printf('o');
        fflush(stdout);
        return [something_that_works];
    }
    else {
        return (void *) NULL;
    }
}

fp_holder *a = (fp_holder *) malloc(sizeof(fp_holder));
a->function_pointer = test_fp;
a->next = NULL;
```

So with all that setup, I tried to call a's function_pointer by trying the following:

```
a->function_pointer(0);
(*a->function_pointer)(0);
((*)a->function_pointer)(0);
```

I just cannot figure out why those are not working.
Help would be appreciated! :)

EDIT

What I am trying to do:
Call a's function_pointer with an argument.

I will try out some answers right now and see what happens.

EDIT2

Answered! I was calling it right by doing a->function_pointer(0) but what was giving me a segmentation error [which is what my issue was - and maybe I should have clarified this] was the printf statement and NOT my call. printf needs a string not the char as I put in.

Comment: Have you tried `(a->function_pointer)(0)`;

Comment: @PaulDraper That's the same as `a->function_pointer(0);`. But indeed, it (both) should work. [Proof](http://ideone.com/XUyPP2).

Comment: what error do you get? (if at all?)

Comment: Geez... Just ask and I will add it in...
No need to write "-1 for making us guess" to try and rile up other people.
'I am trying to figure out how to call fp inside a fp_holder.'
Basically, I am trying to call a's function_pointer with an argument of 0.

Comment: @Supervisor Then perhaps describe your problem in a manner so that we do not *need* to guess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your original code actually do

```
printf('H');
```

instead of

```
printf("H");
```

?

Simplified version of the code you posted, with correct arguments to printf:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void* (*function_pointer_t)(int index);

struct function_holder {
    function_pointer_t callback;
};

void* testFn(int i)
{
    printf("testFn %d\n", i);
}

int main(void) {
    struct function_holder fh = { testFn };
    struct function_holder* fhp = &fh;

    fh.callback = testFn;
    fh.callback(1);
    fhp->callback(2);

    return 0;
}
```

works as expected: http://ideone.com/1syLlG

Comment: How is this even remotely related to the original problem? This should be a comment, but not an answer.

Comment: Since one of his attempts to call the function pointer should have worked, it's possible that this error is corrupting memory and causing it to fail.

Comment: @Barmar Possible, but this still doesn't answer the question. And anyway, we don't know what the error is, since OP failed to describe it.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's a long-shot guess, since his post did not contain an accurate description of the problem when I wrote the first version of my answer.

Comment: @kfsone Unfortunately, it still doesn't contain any.

Comment: @H2CO3 Look, it's been a rough day, and I still haven't gotten it together again since reading [this earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750496/c-error-calling-a-class-member-from-a-function) (<< link) question :) I thought some C function pointers might do me good :)

Comment: @H2CO3: I think it _does_ answer the question? The OP wonders why his program crashes, and this is likely to be the cause.

Comment: @kfsone eh... retracted my downvote since this really is [OP's fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751015/void-function-pointer/19751067?noredirect=1#comment29349947_19751015).

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy **Read the question. It's not stated anywhere that the program's crashing.** It could be a compiler error as well.

Comment: @H2CO3: Ah, yes. You are right. (But on the other hand, is (attempting) to use function pointers really consistent with not being able to find the line that the compiler complains about?)

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy No, not quite, you're right in that. That's why the question is bad, misleading, and just caused me to make some presumably wrong guesses. So, after all, this might turn out to have absolutely nothing to do with function pointers at all.

Comment: It was the print. I'm bad with gdb so I didn't realize that was where the error was occurring.
Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

your code has couple of errors. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by this code, however here is your working code.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef void* (*fp)(int index);
typedef struct fp_holder {
    fp function_pointer;
    struct fp_holder *next;
} fp_holder;

void *test_fp(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        printf("H");
        fflush(stdout);
        return "H";
    }
    else if (index == 1) {
        printf("e");
        fflush(stdout);
        return "e";
    }
    else if (index == 2) {
        printf("l");
        fflush(stdout);
        return "l";
    }
    else if (index == 3) {
        printf("l");
        fflush(stdout);
        return "l";
    }
    else if (index == 4) {
        printf("o");
        fflush(stdout);
        return "o";
    }
    else {
        return (void *) NULL;                                                                                                                                    }
    }


int main() {
    fp_holder *a = (fp_holder *) malloc(sizeof(fp_holder));
    a->function_pointer = test_fp;
    a->next = NULL;
    a->function_pointer(0);
}
```